# C++ Auto-vectorization of STL vector on GCC 4.6.3

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, vectorization

***Setup***

I get curious behaviours when trying to vectorize a code on GCC 4.6.3.

In the following is the snippet code using 3 different ways to perform a simple addition.

- loopFunc() uses pointers.
- loopFunc2() uses STL vector directly accessed via operator[].
- loopFunc3() uses STL vector iterators.

The .cpp snippet code is compiled with the following line:

```
g++ -o snippet-tree-vectorize -fdump-tree-optimized -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 -O2 -ftree-vectorize snippet.cpp
```

***Question:***

- loopFunc() and loopFunc3() get vectorized by GCC (easily checkable with -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2)
- loopFunc2() does not get vectorized.

***Would someone have an explanation for that?***

```
typedef int data_type;

void loopFunc(data_type* d1,const data_type* d2,const data_type* d3) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HUGE-1; i++)
            d1[i] = d2[i] + d3[i];
}

void loopFunc2(std::vector<data_type>& d1,const std::vector<data_type>& d2,const std::vector<data_type>& d3) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HUGE-1; i++)
            d1[i] = d2[i] + d3[i];
}

void loopFunc3(std::vector<data_type>& d1,const std::vector<data_type>& d2,const std::vector<data_type>& d3) 
{
    std::vector<data_type>::iterator it1 = d1.begin();
    std::vector<data_type>::const_iterator it2 = d2.begin();
    std::vector<data_type>::const_iterator it3 = d3.begin();
    for(; it1 != d1.end(); it1++,it2++,it3++)
            *it1 = *it2 + *it3;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<data_type> d1(HUGE, 0); 
    std::vector<data_type> d2(HUGE, 1); 
    std::vector<data_type> d3(HUGE, 2); 

    loopFunc(&d1[0],&d2[0],&d3[0]);
    loopFunc2(d1,d2,d3);
    loopFunc3(d1,d2,d3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (To be completely consistent `loopFunc`'s `d2` and `d3` params should be `const data_type*`.) For completeness, do you get the same results at other levels of optimization (`-O3`, `-O1`...)?

Comment: I have just tried, I edited the const to be fully consistent as you suggested and tried with 03 and 01 without any difference

Comment: Oh another thing I hadn't noticed: in `loopFunc` and `loopFunc2` the condition `i < HUGE-1` should be `i < HUGE` (or `i != HUGE`) (arguably this doesn't really impact the question, but still...)

Comment: I eventually could compile you code on a GCC (adding a `#include <vector>` in the source and a `-DHUGE=12345` to the command) and the log contains a note that you could have mentioned in your question: `snippet.cpp:11: note: not vectorized: data ref analysis failed D.7855_12 = *D.7913_28;`. Web-searching "data ref analysis failed" pops up several GCC bug reports...

Comment: Yes and ? We worked on it with a colleague of mine and could not figure it out ? Moreover, with more recent versions of GCC there seems not to be any problem...

Comment: "with more recent versions of GCC there seems not to be any problem" => Well that's a strong hint. Considering this new information + the aforementioned bug reports, it seems that you have an answer to your question :) i.e. "This is probably a bug in GCC 4.6.3". (Maybe `std::vector<T>::operator[]` implies too many pointer indirections for this version to handle, whereas `loopFunc3` like `loopFunc` boils down to direct use of pointers.)